# how to debug a script file using rails debugger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, debugging

I know how to run the rails server in the debug mode, (example using script/setver --debugger ) but how can i debug a script residing in the script directory?

Answer (score 0):

ruby -d path/to/script [--options ...]